# Zend Framework 324 ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE after PHP 5.3 Upgrade

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

When I upgraded to PHP 5.3, I started getting a 324 error in my Zend app where the view attempts to pass the stripDecorators method objects that are not Zend_Form objects.  I was able to fix this, but I can't figure out why the errors only occurred after upgrading to 5.3 (is Zend more "strict" in 5.3+?) and more importantly, why don't I see any errors output to the error log or on screen.

All I see is the `324 ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` screen. Is there a way to capture these errors in logging?

Comment: Are you sure it wasnt your browser causing it? http://www.roezer.com/fixing-chrome-bug-error-324-neterr_empty_response/

Comment: Yes, I get similar errors on other browsers/computers.  And fixing the line (by only passing Zend_Form objects to stripDecorators) prevents the 324 error from being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was Zend Guard that was causing the problems I encountered.  It was installed when we installed PHP 5.3.

It seems that Zend Guard was turning Deprecated errors in "Unknown" errors and halting the system when it encountered them.  I'm not really sure what was going on, but when I disabled Zend Guard, everything went back to normal.